# Python IndexError - Need help sorting key and Value

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, key

I need help sorting my key-value pair. My output is in this url http://pastebin.com/ckKAtP5y. 
However, what I've been trying to do is.

```
{
    "courses": [
        {
            "professors": [
                {
                    "first_name": "Zvezdelina",
                    "last_name": "Stankova",
                    "professor_url": "http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=375269",
                    "helpfullness": 4.3,
                    "clarity": 4.3,
                    "overall_rating": 4.3
                }],
     "course_name": "CHEM 1",
            "course_mentioned_times": 37
        },
        {
            "professors": [
                {
                    "first_name": "Alan",
                    "last_name": "Shabel",
                    "professor_url": "http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=1309831",
                    "helpfullness": 3.9,
                    "clarity": 3.5,
                    "overall_rating": 3.7
                }],
     "course_name": "CHEMISTRY 231",
     "course_mentioned_times": 50
    }
]
```

So what I want to do is I want to compare 'CHEM' and 'CHEMISTRY' in "course_name" and just get me the most 'course_mentioned_times' and remove the other one.  In this case I'd want CHEMISTRY 231 because it's mentioned 50 times.

Here's what I've been helped with so far.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import json

    #'output_info.json is http://pastebin.com/ckKAtP5y
    with open('output_info.json') as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)

    temp_data = data
    greater = []
    len1 = len(data['courses'])
    len2 = len1

    for i in range(0,len1):
        for j in range(0, len2):
            if i==j:
                continue
            if data['courses'][i]['course_name'][0] == temp_data['courses'][j]['course_name'][0]:
                if data['courses'][i]['course_name'][1] == temp_data['courses'][j]['course_name'][1]:
                    if data['courses'][i]['course_name'][2] == temp_data['courses'][j]['course_name'][2]:
                        if data['courses'][i]['course_mentioned_times']> temp_data['courses'][j]['course_mentioned_times']:
                            greater.append(i)
                        else:
                            greater.append(j)


    final = []
    for i in greater:
      if i not in final:
        final.append(i)

    list_order = []

    for i in range(0,len(data['courses'])):
        list_order.append(i)

    new_final = []
    for i in list_order:
        if i not in final:
            new_final.append(i)

    for i in new_final:
        if i!=new_final[0]:
            i=i-1
        data['courses'].pop(i)

    # Writing the new json data back to data.json file.
    with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
```

This code gives me an IndexError 
    data['courses'].pop(i)
IndexError: pop index out of range

Comment: Only for CHEM? What about MATH? Do you want to get the **max** of course_mentioned_times for similar names? I don't get it

Comment: Yes, I want max of course_mentioned_times for similar names. So for MATH aswell.

Comment: How do you plan to match them if you have courses like: **B 103**. I also see one like `"course_name": " 7",`.

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. In cases like those -> I'd just append them into my dictionary anyhow.

Comment: Just for the record - since it's hard to discern if this is what you want - [Python dictionaries cannot be sorted](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52306-to-sort-a-dictionary/).

Comment: @AkshatMahajan Sorting isn't how exactly I'd word this. All I am asking is just get the most mentioned courses name from similar courses name and append it to a dictionary. That's literally  the entire point of this thread.

Comment: @Benji what if two similar courses have the same **course_mentioned_times** ?

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. We just pick one out of two in that case. Doesn't matter which one. As they're both mentioned same amount of times.

Comment: @Benji  _define_ similar in this context. Are two titles similar only if one is a substring of the other?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan Simiar being said. I've done a split on my class name. Such as .split()[0] - Which will just give me CHEM and CHMISTRY instead of CHEM 1234 or CHMISTIRY 3245 whatever the class number might be. So I'm comparing the first string.

Comment: @Benji yeah, but CHEM and CHEMISTRY are not the same as C or CS, right?

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. Indeed. To clear out the confusion, you can just compare the first few letters and see if they're same. - If they are then boom they're considered same class.

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. I also figured out fuzywuzzy matcher which gives you a ratio of the class. I do not know how to do syntax but fuzywuzzy gives you a ratio of 2 strings and tells you the string matching percentage. So we could do if percentage == 80 then considered same class. That was just an option but I have no idea how to use fuzzywuzzy in this situation.;

Comment: @Benji: Does this help? See: https://dpaste.de/u3HT

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. Hey that is certainly what I need. How did you do that, however also. Is there a way to put that in loop. Because the output I give you isn't consistent. It needs to be updated all the time. And Also, I'd like professor array for that one course. Like the same exact format as my output_info.json is.

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. JUst to make sure, you are returning me the MOST mentioned courses right? Out of all the similar courses.

Comment: @Benji, yes. You could confirm that by checking your data with my output. Btw, I don't understand your

Comment: @Andres Perez-Albela H. , that is indeed what I exactly needed. Now you know how those classes have an array called professors like in http://pastebin.com/ckKAtP5y. I'd like professor array in there aswell which consists first_name last_name etc for that class.

Comment: @Benji, this is my last output: http://pastebin.com/LRsXHnsf

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. That's exactly what I wanted. Could I get a script for that? I'll need to learn how to do that myself aswell.

Comment: @Benji just added my code as an answer

Answer (score 1):

**After a lot of back and forth in question's comments:**

```
#coding:utf-8

import json

filename = 'data.json'

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    courses = data.get('courses', None)

    if courses:
        keys = sorted(set([course.get('course_name', None).strip().split()[0][0:3] for course in courses]))

        results = {'courses': {}}

        for key in keys:
            results['courses'][key] = []
            temp = {}
            for course in courses:
                course_name = course.get('course_name', None)
                professors = course.get('professors', None)
                if course_name.strip().split()[0][0:3] == key:
                    course_mentioned_times = course.get('course_mentioned_times')
                    temp[course_name] = {'course_mentioned_times':course_mentioned_times, 'professors': professors}
            results['courses'][key] = temp
    else:
        raise Exception('No courses could be found on {}'.format(filename))

def get_most_mentioned(name):
    name = name[0:3]
    data = results.get('courses', None).get(name)
    max_mentioned_times = max(map(lambda m: data.get(m, None).get('course_mentioned_times'), data.keys()))

    most_mentioned = []
    for course_name, values in data.items():
        course_mentioned_times = values.get('course_mentioned_times', None)
        if course_mentioned_times == max_mentioned_times:
            most_mentioned.append({'course_name': course_name, 'course_mentioned_times': course_mentioned_times, \
                'professors': values.get('professors')})
    return most_mentioned

print "Course with most mentioned times:"
print "---------------------------------"
for key in keys:
    print "[*] For Key '{}':".format(key)
    for item in get_most_mentioned(key):
        course_name = item.get('course_name', None)
        print "    Course Name: {}".format(course_name)
        print "    Mentioned Times: {}\n".format(item.get('course_mentioned_times'))
        print "    Professors:\n"
        for i, professor in enumerate(item.get('professors', None), start=1):
            print "         {}) Full name: {} {}".format(i, professor.get('first_name'), professor.get('last_name'))
            print "            URL: {}".format(professor.get('professor_url'))
            print "            Helpfullness: {}".format(professor.get('helpfullness'))
            print "            Clarity: {}".format(professor.get('clarity'))
            print "            Overall_rating: {}".format(professor.get('overall_rating'))
            print ""
    print ""
```

Comment: You're a life saver ;)

Comment: @Benji I appreciate it helped! Please set this as the answer for your question if that's the case.

Comment: Perez Albela One last question haha. So I'm trying to sort my json file and just print the top 20. Being said Max to Minimum value. Like put the max  course mentioned times on the top of my json file. Like sort it in a way where it's max to minimum. http://pastebin.com/S0R0tWUH -> I changed your code to that so I can save the output in my json filehttp://pastebin.com/mqCACCP8

Comment: @Benji currently AFK, I'll help you later or tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
import collections

with open('output_info.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

courses = data['courses']

courses_by_prefix = collections.defaultdict(list)

for course in courses:
    prefix = course['course_name'].split(' ', 2)[0].upper()[:3]
    courses_by_prefix[prefix].append(course)


results = []

for prefix, courselist in courses_by_prefix.items():
    mosttimes = max(courselist, key=lambda c: c['course_mentioned_times'])
    results.append(mosttimes)

print(results)
```